# What does this mean >both 2>&1?

Tags: linux

I have a question like this " What is the correct syntax to redirect both standard output and standard error into the same file both?" and the answer is `>both 2>&1` why is this answer correct please explain to me?

What does it mean? `>both 2>&1`

Comment: It means you redirect `stdout` to `both` and then you redirect `stderr` to the same place as `stdout` (order matters here). Check out the documentation on redirection, https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html.

Answer (score 1):

`>file` means redirect standard output to the given *file*. And `2>&1` means redirect standard error to the same descriptor as standard output.

Files are internally (in code) manipulated by descriptors. When you open a file, system gives you in return a descriptor (an object to read/write the file). Linux gives you three descriptors by default: 0 (standard input), 1 (standard output), and 2 (standard error). These 3 descriptors are generally connected to the terminal. Shells (like bash) give you the ability to redirect (change the connection) of them by the use of `<`, `>`, and `2>` operators (that correspond to [`open()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)). These must be followed by a filename, but you can use a special syntax to connect one to another making both aliases to the same file; thus `2>&1` means duplicate descriptor 1 to descriptor 2 (internally this operation is a call to [`dup()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html)).